# Make use case diagram for nosql database

Tags: mongodb, nosql, uml, diagram, use-case

I make a website using MongoDB as a database, I know MongoDB is NoSQL, what diagram can I make with NoSQL database, can I make a use-case diagram, UML?

Comment: I don't see the how the type of database is related to the type of diagrams you want to make.

Comment: use cases are about *what* to do rather than *how* to do, so the technology you use is out of subject. Because the schema is optional for MongoDB perhaps you want to speak about class (diagram) rather than use case (diagram) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Moon Modeler](https://www.datensen.com) for MongoDB and NoSQL data modeling. It supports the creation of ER diagrams - ideal for the definition and visualization of your MongoDB structures. And from the diagram, you can generate schema validation scripts.

Disclaimer: I work at Datensen.